# 301 redirect some requests to non-existent files in a directory, while 404'ing all others

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-301

I need to 301 redirect 40 specific broken URL's within the directory /SOMESLUG/ to the correct/new pages, while returning a 404 error for all other pages within /SOMESLUG/ that don't exist.

We're using something like (note the names don't follow an easy pattern as in the example):

```
Redirect 301 /SOMESLUG/wrong1.html /SOMESLUG/right1.html
Redirect 301 /SOMESLUG/wrong2.html /SOMESLUG/right2.html
...
Redirect 301 /SOMESLUG/wrong40.html /SOMESLUG/right40.html
```

However, as long as we have the rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/SOMESLUG/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sumeslug [R=404,L]
```

in the htaccess file (even after the 301 redirect directive), the redirect fails, just returning a 404 page.

Is there a way to accomplish this in htaccess, or do I need to write a standalone script?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do that in .htaccess itself. Just don't mix mod_alias and mod_rewrite. Better to handle it all via mod_rewrite.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^SOMESLUG/wrong1\.html$ /SOMESLUG/right1.html [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^SOMESLUG/wrong2\.html$ /SOMESLUG/right2.html [L,R=301,NC]

# will not be executed for real files, directories or links
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^SOMESLUG(/.*|)$ - [R=404,L]
```

Also I will highly recommend you to use [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html) if you can control over Apache config.

Comment: Thanks! What's the significance of -MultiViews in the context of this rewrite rule?

Comment: `-` is not an error, its there on purpose. It means don't redirect to anything just return 404 to browser and default 404 page will show up.  `MultiViews` lots of problem in mod_rewrite hence better to turn it off this option.